# SUSI custom policy does not return user claims in token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using a custom policy for Sign In/Sign Up flow and faced an issue when claims are collected while the user signs up (such as givenName, surname, and displayName) are not populated in the token. These claims are written in the AD local account (I double-checked them), but they are not returned back after signing in or signing up.

Here are the final orchestrations step (user read + send claims)

```
 <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
   <ClaimsExchanges>
     <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
   </ClaimsExchanges>
 </OrchestrationStep>
 <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
```

As you can see above it uses AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId TechnicalProfile from TrustFrameworkBaseFile (I didn't modify it).
Here is AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <!-- Optional claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

This page helped me to figure out the issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#provide-optional-claims-to-your-app.
The output claims provided to token should be put in the RelyingParty section in OutpuClaims